# Comparing uncertain string to known string in python pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I receive tsv files from people that are generally in one of two formats:

```
# format 1
sample    100    200    1
sample    200    300    2
sample    300    400    3
sample    400    500    X
```

or

```
# format 2
sample    100    200    chr1
sample    200    300    chr2
sample    300    400    chr3
sample    400    500    chrX
```

Sometimes I need the file to be in the first format, and sometimes I need it to be in the second format. I know which format I need it to be in prior to running my python code, so I have been receiving their csv file, and if I have a file in format 1 and need it in format 2 I run the following awk script:

```
awk '{print $1, $2, $3, "chr"$4}' tester.csv
```

which outputs format 1 to be like format 2, and is interpreted by my python code as a text file no problems. I can do the same thing in reverse using sed:

```
sed 's/chr//' testerchr.txt
```

which outputs format 2 to be like format 1. I then run my python code, which has a comparison as follows:

```
testchr = [(1, 'ACGTGCTAGCTG'), (2, 'ACGATGCTAGCT'), (3, 'GCTCGT')]
regions = pd.read_csv('./tester.csv', sep='\t', names=['Sample', 'pos1', 'pos2', 'Chr'])

for x,y in testchr: # [(1, ACGTGCTAGCTGA), (2, ACGATGCTAGCT), (3, GCTCGT)]
    chrm = str(x)
    for u,v,a,b in zip(regions.Sample, regions.pos1, regions.pos2, regions.Chr):
        if str(b) == chrm:
            #process data
```

So generally I have a list of tuples

If I preprocess the data (using the awk or sed command prior to python code), I never have any issues. I was just wondering if anyone could propose a way in which I did not have to preprocess the data. Essentially, my python code could take in data in either format and function properly **without having to make any modifications to the input, and without letting the program know up front which format the input file is**.

Thanks,
Dennis

Comment: Can i point out that if... elif... both do the same thing "chrm = str(x)", so you might just skip the if..elif.. and go "chrm = str(x)" directly?

Comment: Yeah absolutely, thanks for pointing that out that redundancy! I edited the code. honestly I don't even need chrm = str(x), I could just have if str(b) == str(x). I'll fix that at some point :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make it a function and set a value for format 1 and format 2. something like if val == something change the 'Char' column to format 1 else change it to format 2:

```
def myFuction(df, val):
    if val == 1:
        df['Chr'] = df['Chr'].str[3:] # strip first 3 characters
        # do stuff with format 1
    else:
        df['Chr'] = 'chr'+df['Chr'] # add 'chr' in front
        # do stuff with format 2

format_val = input('Format Value: ')
myFunction(df, int(format_val))
```

Comment: Thanks, I like the idea and I will +1 it. I am just looking to see if there is a way that the user of the program doesn't need to know anything going into it. They can just submit the file as long as it is in the proper format and let it fly.

Comment: @d_kennetz are you using two different codes depending on the format?

Comment: No, the comparison above would work just as long as `testchr` and `regions` have the same format. But basically, the list `testchr` will only ever be in one of the two formats above. `testchr` is actually a file that I parse into a list of tuples. Item 0 in each tuple is either in the format `1` or `chr1` etc... and I know the format the tuple will be in based on the name of the reference file selected, so I know how to format the user input file accordingly.